# fatal: fail to push some reps to my-app on heroku when trying to push node doc

Tags: node.js, heroku

**strong text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ORL5.png)
I tryied these commands to deploy heroku app but this gives an error of "failed to push some refs to my-app"

1. heroku create
   2.git remote -v
   3.git push heroku main

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2XRN.png)

Comment: Please add your code here in ```code block``` instead of adding as an image.

Comment: My apologies, i'm new to this...
But I fixed my problem..